# Rewrite "https://files.mydomain.com/files" to "https://files.mydomain.com"

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Currently, I am able to visit:  `https://files.mydomain.com/files`.   Even if I go to `https://files.mydomain.com`, it will redirect automatically to `https://files.mydomain.com/files` successfully.

Instead, I would like for NGINX to automatically rewrite `https://files.mydomain.com/files` -> `https://files.mydomain.com`

**My current NGINX code:**

```properties
http {

    server {
        
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {

            listen       80;
            server_name  files.mydomain.com;
            location / {
                return 301 https://files.mydomain.com$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2; 
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
            server_name  files.mydomain.com;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            location / {
                return 301 https://$host/files;
            } 
            location /files {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:89;
            }
    }

    #Root Domain
    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2; 
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
            server_name_in_redirect off;
            server_name  www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
            log_not_found off;

        location / {
            root   /inetpub/wwwroot;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

**My best attempt:**
Unfortunately, it just takes me to the "Welcome to NGINX" webpage when I visit:
`https://files.mydomain.com`

```properties
http {

    server {
        
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {

            listen       80;
            server_name  files.mydomain.com;
            location / {
                return 301 https://files.mydomain.com$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2; 
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
            server_name  files.mydomain.com;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            location ^~ /files {
                rewrite ^/files/?(.*)$ https://files.mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:89/files;
            }
    }

    #Root Domain
    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2; 
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
            server_name_in_redirect off;
            server_name  www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
            log_not_found off;

        location / {
            root   /inetpub/wwwroot;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** [**Final answer**] ***

After several tests, the following configuration covers almost all the prerequisites.

Both `/` and `/files/` are forwarded to `localhost:89/files/`.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate .../fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key .../privkey.pem;

    server_name files.mydomain.com;

    location /files/ { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:89/files/;
    }       

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:89/files/;
    }
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

In this real case, only a small issue at first visit :

> When I visit https://files.mydomain.com for the first time, it
> automatically forwards to:
> https://files.mydomain.com/files/login.aspx. After I authenticate with
> my credentials, it automatically forwards to
> https://files.mydomain.com/files instead of
> https://files.mydomain.com. However the good news is if I stay logged
> in and revisit https://files.mydomain.com, it will continue to stay
> at: https://files.mydomain.com.

[**Initial answer**]

I know you are asking for url rewriting, but have you tried the `proxy_pass`+`alias` way?

My tests at home seem ok. I simply put files in a folder and use the following nginx configuration (I use port 8443 as a fake SSL port):

```
server {
    listen 8443;
    server_name files.ssl.localhost;
    root D:/WEB;

    location / {
        alias D:/WEB/secretfolder/files/;
        autoindex on; # or not, only to test folder listing
    }

    location /files/ { #beware the trailing slash
        proxy_pass http://files.ssl.localhost:8443/; #beware the trailing slash
    }
}
```

`http://files.ssl.localhost:8443/files/` and `http://files.ssl.localhost:8443` both point to the same directory listing:

[image: directory listing]

and we can get, for example, the contents of file.txt:
[image: file.txt contents]

I hope this approach matches your goals or makes sense for anyone else.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting with your current solution.  Could you change your answer so it matches MY desired URL and current proxy_pass line: proxy_pass http://localhost:89/files;  I can give it a shot.

Comment: @MKANET Yes I could, I'm going to. But, in your nginx blocks, no block defines a server listening on port 89. That was what I was stuck on.

Comment: Thank you.  Maybe I'm not understanding correctly..... `http://localhost:89/files` is an existing IIS ASP.NET application that's already listening on port 89.  NGINX can't also listen on the same port too on the same machine concurrently.

Comment: @MKANET, this explains that ^^ Another edit has been done. I cross fingers.

Comment: your `Update 2` looks identical to what I'm already using.  It only makes the URL:  `https://files.mydomain.com/files`.  It doesn't NOT change it to: `https://files.mydomain.com` unfortunately.  I think it will need the correct NGINX rewrite code.

Comment: @MKANET, thanks for your feedback. It does not **change** the url, but both `https://files.mydomain.com/files` and `https://files.mydomain.com` point to `http://localhost:89/files/`, same result for me. If your goal is to **mask** the `/files/` part, maybe `IIS` listening on port 89 should expose `/` location and route requests to `.../files/` real folder, so nginx could proxy requests to `http://localhost:89/`, IMHO. That was the goal of `UPDATE 1`.

Comment: when I try to go to the path `https://files.mydomain.com` I get the error in the screenshot below.  It looks like it's trying to access the resource `https://files.mydomain.com/files/files/login.aspx` probably trying to validate the login first.  However, /files/files/ is not correct.  https://imgur.com/Z9f86bJ

Comment: @MKANET Thanks for the screenshot. So it could mean that IIS routes / requests to the right location itself. Fine! So, let's empty the caches of your navigator (because of previous hard redirections), and try the **`UPDATE 3`**.

Comment: Phillipe unfortunately, with UPDATE3, when I go to the URL:  `https//files.mydomain.com` or `https//files.mydomain.com/files` it goes to the root of my IIS website:  `https//mydomain.com`...same as `http//localhost:89` _(if accessed locally on the server)_.  Ultimately, `https//files.mydomain.com` or `https//files.mydomain.com/files` should be the same as `http//localhost:89/files`, not `http//localhost:89`.  Sorry, StackOverflow wouldn't let me use `:` character in the URLs for this comment.

Comment: @MKANET, this is what I understood when writing UPDATE 3. If you need to proxy to `http://localhost:89/files/` **UPDATE 2** should work. Would you try again the configuration in **UPDATE 2**?

Comment: Philippe, **UPDATE 2** is almost PERFECT!  Just a small issue.  When I visit `https://files.mydomain.com` **for the first time**, it automatically forwards to: `https://files.mydomain.com/files/login.aspx`.  After I authenticate with my credentials, it automatically forwards to `https://files.mydomain.com/files` instead of `https://files.mydomain.com`.  **_However_** the good news is if I stay logged in and revisit `https://files.mydomain.com`, it will continue to stay at: `https://files.mydomain.com`.  Can you think of a way to fix the small issue immediately after authenticating?

Comment: Good morning @MKANET ;) Please, would you test **UPDATE 4**?

Comment: Bonjour Philippe!  I think you have a typo in your **UPDATE 4**.  Specifically in this line:  `return 302 https://files.mydomain.com.fr$1;`.  I tried changing it to `return 302 https://files.mydomain.com/$1;`  However, I am getting an error with that rewrite code.  This is what I do:  First, I go to: `https://files.mydomain.com`  Then, I am presented with the login screen at: `https://files.mydomain.com/login.aspx`.  When I enter my username/password, my browser immediately returns the following error: `files.mydomain.com says HTTP Error:  200- (Response content-type in not application/json)`

Comment: @MKANET, sorry for the trailing .fr (find and replace issue ^^). I have updated : `return 302 https://files.mydomain.com$1` (no slash before $1) . Please test and let me know.

Comment: Philippe, unfortunately changing it to did not make any difference in behavior after changing the line in **UPDATE 4** to `return 302 https://files.mydomain.com$1;`   First, I go to: `https://files.mydomain.com`. Then, I am presented with the login screen at: `https://files.mydomain.com/login.aspx`. When I enter my username/password, my browser immediately returns the following error: files.mydomain.com says HTTP Error:  200- (Response content-type in not application/json).

Comment: @MKANET, in my country we say that, sometimes, "best" is the enemy of "good" (enough). **UPDATE 2** was almost perfect, I'm going to dig further more.

Comment: @MKANET, may you have a look @ **UPDATE 5**?

Comment: **UPDATE5** displays all files listed in the REAL path even with IIS directory browsing disabled. It bypasses IIS webserver completely.  I am happy with "almost perfect" solution **UPDATE2**!  I think you have earned it.  Can you please edit your answer to ONLY show **UPDATE2** as the solution before I accept it as the answer?  Or, edit it a little so its clearer that **UPDATE2** is the answer. It will be easier for others to see the answer in the future.

Comment: @MKANET, I'm glad to read you ;) I edited the post with the finale answer at top, I don't know if is recommended on SO to delete all the consecutive answers. Probably yes, as they are useless.

Comment: great job, you earned it.  Nobody else was willing or able to figure this out... so, you deserve this bounty.

Comment: @MKANET, many thanks for this and for your patience ;) Btw, I wonder if `location /files` with no trailing slash wouldn't be better in your case. If you have time to test it, please let me know. Thanks & all the best for you.

Comment: Sure you're welcome.  Removing the trailing slash for `location /files` didn't seem to change anything its behavior.  It still has the small isshe.  Do you think I should leave the `/` or remove it?  I'm not sure what its for.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure either. It's beyond my knowledge :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `return` and not a `rewrite` for a redirect. This should work:

```
location /path/to-your-page-name {
  return 301 /new-path/to-your-new-page-name;
}
```

So, if you want domains resolving to ~/files and assuming that `root` points to `/inetpub/wwwroot` do the following:

```
http {

server {        
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  files.mydomain.com;
        location / {
            return 301 https://files.mydomain.com$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2; 
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  files.mydomain.com;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        location / {
            return 301 https://files.mydomain.com/files;
        }
}

#Root Domain
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2; 
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        server_name  www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
        log_not_found off;

    location / {
        #root   /inetpub/wwwroot;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
           return 301 https://files.mydomain.com/files;
        }
    }
}
```

You might also have to set `server_name_in_redirect on;` depending on your configuration.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you.  Unfortunately, that just takes me to the "Welcome to NGINX webpage".

Comment: @MKANET please check my new modified answer.

Comment: you are right `root` points to /inetpub/wwwroot,  I tried your latest code _exactly_ like you have.  I first cleared browser cache.  When I enter `https//files.mydomain.com` in my web browser, it takes me to `https//files.mydomain.com/files` and get the browser error **EER_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.  Even it doesnt have an error, it doesn't go to the right URL.  Also, when I go to my root domain:  `https//mydomain.com`, it takes me to `https//files.mydomain.com` instead of `https//mydomain.com` and displays the same **EER_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.  Basically it broke everything

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't put `:` in my previous comment..  I took them out to be able to post my comment.  Thank you for trying though.

Comment: I even tried `server_name_in_redirect on;` insetad of it being off.  It make no difference.